# Threads and Synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the below code for Thread Synchronization Method and a Synchronization Block

```
public class ThreadSynchronizationPartI {
    public static int myValue=1;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Thread t=new Thread(()->
        {
            while(true)
            {
            updateBalance();
                }
        });
        t.start();

        t=new Thread(()->{
        while(true)
        {
            monitorBalance();
        }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    public static synchronized void updateBalance(){
        System.out.println("start "+myValue);
         myValue = myValue + 1;
        //    myValue = myValue - 1;
        System.out.println("end "+myValue);

    }
    public static synchronized void monitorBalance(){
        int b=myValue;
        if(b>1)
        {
            System.out.println("B is greater than 1 by"+(b-1));
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Why Does it give the following output:
    start 1
    end 2
    start 2
    end 3
    start 3
    end 4
    start 4
    end 5
    start 5
    end 6
    start 6
    end 7
    start 7
    end 8
    B is greater than 1 by 7

Can anyone explain?

Comment: because before end print statement you have added 1 to myvalues

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?  That updateBalance and monitorBalance would be running in parallel?  Using threads means they *could* be, not necessarily that they *will* be.

Comment: Why does the codestops at 8 why doesnt it continue?

Comment: Because that is what it ought to do? Why do *you* expect it to do anything else?

Comment: I am asking how does the compiler gets to know stop at 8, i havent given any condition like that in the code  then how is it working like that

Comment: You haven't explicitly. But you do `System.exit(1)` - so it will stop the program. The "8" is mere random. If you execute this 1000 times, I guess it will sometimes also stop at 7, 9, ...

Comment: Thank you very much thats what the answer i was expectin

Comment: The main starts two threads and then hits the end of the program and ends.  Any active threads not launched as a daemon end as well (something a bit ugly to do in general.. you should always 'nicely' wait for the threads to end on their own, and only after a timeout abruptly end threads).  If you want to wait for the threads to end, consider calling t.join() in order to wait for your thread to finish.

Answer (score 1):

The execution of your program will start from main(). Initially the value of myValue is 1 and a new thread t will be created. Until the condition is true the while loop will be executed. When the control will reach updateBalance(), it will jump to that method and the println() will print the value of myValue which is 1. Hence the output will be : `start 1` it will then increase the value of myValue to +1 and as a result the next println() would print the output as : `end 2`. When the condition for next thread will be true in while loop, the control will be transferred there. The monitorBalance() will be called and b is initialized the value of myValue. When the condition `b>1` evaluates to true it will print : `B is greater than 1 by (b-1)`.